# Error : Trying to get property of non-object when I'm trying to get attribute from relational table Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, relational

Please help me.. 
So my case is here:

I have a `to` attribute from table email

[image]

I also have `group_id` attribute from table group

[image]

to attribute and `group_id` is same. the value of `to` taken from `group_id`.

I want display `to` attribute to be `name` of `group_id` in view (as pict 2 shown).

I already make this code in my email model

```
public function getTo() {
    return $this->hasMany(Group::className(), ['group_id' => 'group_id']);
}
```

and then in my email view

```
$group = Group::findOne(['group_id'=>$model->to]);
```

this is in gridview

```
['label'  => 'To','value' => $group->name,],
```

and this is in my email controller

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->to = Yii::$app->group->group_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Email Model your relation must be like this

```
public function getTo() {
    return $this->hasOne(Group::className(), ['group_id' => 'to']);
}
```

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object
1. in C:\xampp\htdocs\projek\advanced\backend\views\email\view.php at line 52
43444546474849505152535455565758596061                        </p>
 
    <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            // 'email_id:email',
 
           [
                'label'  => 'To',
                'value' => $group->name,